# What is the correct approach / logic to access the activity which inflates a layout with custom view from this view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm developing an application in which I have a dashboard with 4 buttons. Each button starts a new Intent to a different Activity. Each Activity inflates the same layout that consists of the custom view. In the custom view is a ViewPager. In the ViewPager I want to display a strings that resides in the arrays in the mentioned above activities. Should I pass those arrays to the custom view and display it in the ViewPager? If so how can I pass them? How the Custom View would know from which activity they come from? I know that the 'sender' activity will be the one that is currently running but how can I check it? Or should I just make the arrays static and easily access them? In this case I would also need to know which activity to access. Please advise or maybe there is a better way of implementing it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Intents let you [start other activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity), also allows you to pass primitives, primitive arrays/Lists as well as custom `Parcelable` objects to other activities.

You can pass array data, starter activity name etc here. Or you can use [getCallingActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) to know the sender activity.

UPDATE:

You can pass data to custom views in `onCreate()` , if You have setter methods in Custom View class.

For more complex communication, Interface your activity to its child view as shown:

Interface:

```
public interface CustomViewParent {
    //----add as many communication methods you want---
    public String[] getData();
    public void doSomething();
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements CustomViewParent {

// ------------------------ INTERFACE METHODS ------------------------


// --------------------- Interface CustomViewParent ---------------------

    @Override
    public String[] getData() {
        return new String[]{"data1","data2"};
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Custom view called me !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

// -------------------------- OTHER METHODS --------------------------

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //----here we set the parent--
        ((CustomView)findViewById(R.id.my_custom_view)).setParent(this);
    }
}
```

Accept and use this interface in Custom View:

```
public class CustomView extends ViewPager {
// ------------------------------ FIELDS ------------------------------

    private CustomViewParent parent;

// --------------------------- CONSTRUCTORS ---------------------------

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

// --------------------- GETTER / SETTER METHODS ---------------------

    public void setParent(CustomViewParent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

// ---------------------------- INITIALIZE-----------------------------
    private void init() {
    //-----initialize/inflate custom views-----

    //-----calls to parent, !! do not forget the null check !! ----
        if(parent != null){
            String[] data = parent.getData();

            parent.doSomething();
        }

    //----add data from parent to Views etc---

    }
}
```

Comment: The custom view is not started via the intents but it's inflated from the xml layout. I want to coummunicate this view and it's children with its parent activity. Thanks anyway.